# How I do this subquery correctly?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I get error 400 on Cosmos when I put this query with subquery. I need do this task on one query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT VALUE c.Nome 
FROM c 
WHERE c.Id = 0456 
  AND c.Tipo NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT VALUE c.Tipo 
                     FROM c 
                     WHERE c.Materiais IN (55))
  AND c.Materiais NOT IN (55)
```

The two queries work separately. How can I do it together?

Comment: Is `c` really the name of the table?

Comment: This shouldn't be tagged with `python`

Comment: What are you trying to compute with this query?

Comment: what is error you are getting ?

Comment: Failed to query item for container Construct: {"code":400,"body":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Message: {\"errors\":[{\"severity\":\"Error\",\"location\":{\"start\":85,\"end\":91},\"code\":\"SC1001\",\"message\":\"Syntax error, incorrect syntax near 'SELECT'.\"}]}

Comment: @JaquelineTeixeira Hi,any updates?

Answer (score 0):

As i know, cosmos db doesn't support the format of your sub query sql which is similar to normal relational database sql. I viewed the sample code of [official documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-subquery) for sub query,you could try my sql:

```
SELECT DISTINCT VALUE c.Nome 
FROM c 
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT VALUE c.Tipo 
                     FROM c 
                     WHERE c.Materiais IN (55)) m
where c.Tipo != m.Tipo and c.Materiais NOT IN (55)
```

Any concern or any further issues,please let me know here.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer but its returns a empty list. This is a different result that should be

Comment: @JaquelineTeixeira Would you please post some sample data in your answer so that i can create a sql which works for you.